# Moving Averages and Seasonality Filters

Tags: google-earth-engine

What would be a way to compute moving averages of a time series in GEE? Consider we imported an image collection X and filtered by start and finish dates.

```js
var Y =ee.ImageCollection(X.filterDate(start,finish));
```

I want to be able to compute moving averages of the time series

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are issues with this example (clouds), but it illustrates how to do what you want using joins, map and reduce:

```js
var l5toa = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT5_L1T_TOA");
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-120.69580078125, 37.49229399862877]);

var collection = l5toa.filterBounds(geometry);

var join = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'images'
});

var timeField = 'system:time_start';

var diffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 17,
  leftField: timeField, 
  rightField: timeField
});

var threeNeighborJoin = join.apply({
  primary: collection, 
  secondary: collection, 
  condition: diffFilter
});

var smoothed = ee.ImageCollection(threeNeighborJoin.map(function(image) {
  var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(image.get('images'));
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(collection.mean());
}));

var smooth = ee.Image(smoothed.filterDate('2008-06-01', '2008-07-01').first());
Map.addLayer(smooth, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.4}, 'original');
Map.addLayer(smooth, {bands: ['B4_1', 'B3_1', 'B2_1'], max: 0.4}, 'smooth');
```

More info [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1J1rUtf-bkfaJwYJY-tU17kzKI4U8FnF7Q2_VWqWdaak/edit#slide=id.g4954714e1_18) and [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mNIRB90jwLuASO1JYas1kuOXCLbOoy1Z4NlV1qIXM10/edit#heading=h.s5pg8lzfp985).

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of the syntax of var diffFilter and var threeNeighborJoin? I do understand the temporal cadence of L8 is 17 days, so is 'difference' the calculation of consecutive values in milliseconds? Does threeNeigborjoin mean the average of three consecutive values? What if I want to take the rolling average of 5 consecutive values?

Comment: `difference` is 17 days in milliseconds.  `threeNeighborJoin` is a `FeatureCollection` in which each image stores a reference (`images`) to whatever images pass the filter (i.e. is within 17 days).  The mean is computed by `collection.mean()`.  For a 5 day filter, use 34 days in the filter.  You can discover all that by printing intermediate results.